# How to set a layout that blocks the buttons of the layout that's below it

Tags: android

Let's say I have some views in this structure:

```
<RelativeLayout>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/below"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/above"></ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The imageView below has `setOnClickListener(event)` while the ImageView above is just a normal ImageView, and they are both the same size, one overlapping the other.

How can I set it such that the ImageView above "physically" blocks the ImageView below so when the user clicks on `above` the click won't "pass through" (The `event` that is to be triggered when clicked on `below` will not be triggered)

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: the imageviews are overlapping?

Comment: Don't set the onClickListener until you want it to function. You can the set it to null to disable it again.

Answer (score 0):

Use setEnabled (boolean enabled) method. Make the imageView setEnabled (false) if you want it to be blocked.
[setEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29)

Set the parameter for above imageView android:enabled="false". And in onClick() method, when the imageView below will be clicked just set above.setEnabled(true).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two ImageView just to overlap those then I think you better create a [Layer-List Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) with two images and use it in a single ImageView

For Your Acknowledgement

> A LayerDrawable is a drawable object that manages an array of other
>   drawables. Each drawable in the list is drawn in the order of the
>   list—the last drawable in the list is drawn on top.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.above)).bringToFront();
```